# How to rewrite a negated line?

Tags: javascript, logic

Negating takes me hours of trial and error until nothing breaks, any method of negating other than intuitively? For example:

```
//x and y are whole numbers

!((x<9) && (y<=(8-x)))
((x>8) || (y>(8-x)))
```

Comment: Learn and understand basic propositional logic: http://editthis.info/logic/Propositional_Logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is to ignore questions about the domain of values, and treat this as an entirely logical problem. Then we can break it down into cases such as:

```
!(A || B) ~= !A && !B
!(A && B) ~= !A || !B
!(!A) ~= A
!(x > y) ~= x <= y
!(x >= y) ~= x < y
```

The first two can easily be extended:

```
!(A || B || C || D || ...) ~= !A && !B && !C && !D && ...
!(A && B && C && D && ...) ~= !A || !B || !C || !D || ...
```

So, for one of your examples, we have:

```
!((x < 9) && (y <= (8 - x)))
!(x < 9) || !(y <= (8 - x))
(x >= 9) || (y > (8 - x))
```

We could leave it as this, but as you had additional domain information, ("x and y are whole numbers"), you might incorporate it to return a slightly less specific, but accurate enough in context answer, such as

```
(x > 8) || (y > (8 - x))
```

You would have to decide on a case-by-case basis whether this is worth the additional steps. What it might gain is a somewhat reduced codebase, it can also lose in a less transparent link to the original format.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ajax333221; bad things happen when I answer late at night!  :-)